# php error with post inside variable

Tags: php, syntax-error

Trying to do this:

```
$product_description =  'Credit balance of &#8364;' $_POST['creditamount'] ;
```

Want to display that post inside my variable but get this

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /var/www/account/credits/moneybookers/process.php on line 48
```

What am i doing wrong??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the concatenation operator `.`

Your code should look like this:

`$product_description =  'Credit balance of &#8364;' . $_POST['creditamount'];`

Answer (score 2):

You miss a dot behind `'Credit balance of &#8364;'`.

In PHP, you join strings using `.`. Ex.:

```
$new_string = $string_one . "whatever" . $string_two;
```